# Examples of options to bash cd, eg: cd -Pe@ $directory

Tags: bash, cd-command

In `bash 4.4.12`, `help cd` says:

> ```
> Options:
>   -L        force symbolic links to be followed: resolve symbolic
>             links in DIR after processing instances of `..'
>   -P        use the physical directory structure without following
>             symbolic links: resolve symbolic links in DIR before
>             processing instances of `..'
>   -e        if the -P option is supplied, and the current working
>             directory cannot be determined successfully, exit with
>             a non-zero status
>   -@        on systems that support it, present a file with extended
>             attributes as a directory containing the file attributes
> ```

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around these words and my google-fu can't bring up anything.

1. What is an example of when `cd -P` would be preferred over `cd`?
2. How is `cd -L` different to standard `cd`?
3. How could it be possible that the working directory couldn't be determined successfully?
4. What is an example of using `-@`?

Comment: See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=253

Comment: It took me a while to work out that this is the POSIX `sh` being discussed in the link above.
Interestingly, `bash` allows `-e` without `-P`, useful in [@StéphaneChazelas's example 3](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356598/143394), because [`bash`'s `cd` does not seem to be POSIX compliant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356595/examples-of-options-to-bash-cd-eg-cd-pe-directory?noredirect=1#comment632153_356598).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) gives a little more detail.

1. `cd -P` ensures you end up with a “real” path:

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ mkdir -p a/b
   $ ln -s a/b b
   $ cd b
   $ pwd
   /tmp/b
   $ cd -P ../b
   $ pwd
   /tmp/a/b
   ```

   Using `-P` means the symlink from `b` to `a/b` is dereferenced. The interaction with `..` is that `..` is normally processed by removing the previous path component, if there is one; not by checking the path on disk. If you use lots of symlinks this can end up being very confusing.
2. `cd -L` is equivalent to the default `cd`.
3. The current working directory can’t be determined if it’s been deleted:

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   $ mkdir -p c/d
   $ cd c/d
   $ rmdir ../d ../../c
   $ cd ..; echo $?
   cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
   0
   ```

   v.

   ```
   $ cd -Pe ..; echo $?
   cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
   1
   ```
4. This I’m not sure about (I can imagine what it would look like, but Bash just says “`cd`: `-@`: invalid option”; I get the impression this is currently only available on Solaris, it needs `O_XATTR`).

Comment: From my reading of [POSIX.1-2008 (2016 version) `cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html), `bash`'s `cd` is not compliant as it returns `0` in your third example, with or without `-P`. It seems like using `-e` is always a good thing with `bash`.