# How does cd's "-@" parameter work?

Tags: bash, cd-command, xattr

`bash`'s man page (and `help cd`) mentions that `cd` supports a `-@` parameter ("on systems that support it") to "present a file with extended attributes as a directory containing the file attributes"

Is there an example of using this? (Ideally with a commonly present file, or with a setup to create an example (I'm not familiar enough with `xattr` currnelt))

Where is it supported? Everywhere supporting `xattr`s, or is there more kernel support needed? (i.e. Can I use it with an `xattr`-supporting version of OS X, Solaris, FreeBSD, Linux, etc)

My guess is that if a file, `/path/f` has `xattr`s I can do `cd -@ /path/f` and `ls` would then show xattrs as (emulated) "files" in the emulated "directory" `/path/f`? (For this, I assume that the kernel need some kind of support for this simulation, since things like `ls` live outside `bash`, which means that `bash` can't be doing the emulation)

Comment: Related: [Examples of options to bash cd, eg: cd -Pe@ $directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356595/86440).

Comment: I tried `setfattr` on WSL and get `setfattr: test: Operation not supported`, so I'm assuming I need to try a real Linux to see if I can create an xattr on a file for my own testing... (A random XFS and ext4 filesystem gets the same result with the default mount options) (I know OS X makes extended use of xattrs, so it might be testable there)

Comment: @StephenKitt Useful, but no info on `-@` beyond the man page or `help` output there either...

Answer (score 6):

I think `-@` is only supported on Solaris (and systems based on Solaris, such as Illumos). On Solaris, extended attributes can be considered as files in an orthogonal name space; in theory, any file (in the general sense, including directories etc.) can have extended attributes, which themselves can have extended attributes, etc. In order to explore this forest of attributes, there are APIs which allow them to be handled as a tree of files, and this is what `cd -@` uses (and `-@` on other commands). See [`fsattr(5)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1474/fsattr-5.html) for details. This can be limited depending on the supporting file system; for example UFS doesn’t allow directories to be used as attributes, and doesn’t allow attributes to have attributes themselves.

On Solaris, the way this appears to the user is as you suggest:

```
~$ touch test
~$ cd -@ test
/proc/1604/fd/6$ ls
SUNWattr_ro  SUNWattr_rw
/proc/1604/fd/6$ touch attribute
```

This creates an “attribute” extended attribute file attached to the “test” file. `cd -@ attribute` works too, inside the attribute tree, and one can continue down the rabbit hole.

A similar extended attribute API was floated recently (January 2019) for Linux, notably as part of [a discussion on `fs-verity`](https://lwn.net/Articles/775872/).

Comment: Ah, I didin't realise that extended attributes differ that significantly between *nixes... (Other than to a "not enabled" or "not supported" level)