# Why was -H and -L choosen for --dereference-command-line and --dereference in ls as well as for example du?

Tags: posix

Why was `-H` and `-L` choosen for respectively `--dereference-command-line` and `--dereference` in `ls` as well as for example `du`?

I guess `-H` and `-L` were thought to be less commonly used, so could be used in multiple utilities without conflicts. If there is no good historic reason, maybe someone has a good mnemonic device.

Comment: Because we'd used so many letters in `ls` that there weren't many free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice of letters is explained in `man symlink` (*e.g* in [the OpenBSD version](https://man.openbsd.org/symlink.7) or [the Linux version](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html)): a tree walk without dereferencing symlinks to directories is called a physical walk (it follows the “physical” directory structure only), a tree walk dereferencing symlinks to directories is called a logical walk (it follows the “logical” structure overlaid by symlinks on top of the physical structure).

`-L` means “logical”, and `-H` “half-logical” (it starts its tree walk logically then switches to a physical walk). You’ll also find `-P` for “physical”, *e.g.* [`cd -P`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356595/86440).